# Cannot call subclass function in Gnome Shell Extension ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, gnome-shell-extensions

I am trying to write a GNOME shell extension. I have a class which extends a GNOME shell type. Whenever I call class method on this subclass, it throws an error. If I *do not* extend the class, then the method is invoked without a problem.

Example:

This works

```
var Dummy = class Dummy {
  constructor() {}
  foo() {
    log("foo!")
  }
};

let d = new Dummy();
d.foo();

--> RESULT: log shows "foo!"
```

However, this does not work

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
var Dummy = class Dummy extends St.Bin {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  foo() {
    log("foo!")
  }
};

let d = new Dummy();
d.foo();

--> RESULT: TypeError: d.foo is not a function
```

I'm not very proficient in Javascript, and I'm having trouble Googling my way out of this situation.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a bit of mix of Class styles, for couple reasons, but namely because GJS existed before ES6 classes. You should avoid usage of the [`Lang`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/wikis/Modules#lang) module if at all possible.

Sometimes it won't be clear if the object you're subclassing is a native JS class or a GObject. Any object coming from `imports.gi` (GObject Introspection) will be a GObject, while objects coming from say `imports.ui.popupMenu` (an import in GNOME Shell) could be either and you may have to check the source.

If you *are* subclassing a GObject, this is the proper way to subclass:

```js
var Bin = GObject.registerClass({

    // This is optional, but useful to avoid namespace collisions. By
    // convention you prefix your GType's like StBin or GtkBin.
    GTypeName: 'PohoBin',

    // Custom GProperties
    Properties: {
        'example-prop': GObject.ParamSpec.string(
            'example-prop',                     // property name
            'ExampleProperty',                  // nickname
            'An example read write property',   // description
            (GObject.ParamFlags.READWRITE |     // READABLE/READWRITE/CONSTRUCT/etc
             GObject.ParamFlags.CONSTRUCT),
            null                                // implement defaults manually
        )

    }
}, class Bin extends St.Bin {

    // Currently GObjects use `constructor()` for bootstrapping; you
    // should not call this function in GObject subclasses.
    //
    // Instead, you should chain-up to the parent class's _init() function,
    // which takes a dictionary of properties
    _init(params = {}) {
        // Chaining up. If you need to, you can use this opportunity to
        // pull properties from the @params dictionary
        super._init(params);
    }

    get example_prop() {
        if (this._example_prop === undefined) 
            this._example_prop = null;

        return this._example_prop;
    }

    set example_prop(value) {
        if (this.example_prop !== value) {
            this._example_prop = value;
            this.notify('example-prop');
        }
    }

    foo() {
        log(this.example_prop);
    }
});


let obj = new Bin({
    visible: true,            // Clutter.Actor property
    x_align: St.Align.MIDDLE, // St.Bin property
    example_prop: 'example'   // custom property
});

obj.foo();
// expected output: 'example'
```

There is more information about mapping GObject to JavaScript here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/wikis/Mapping

There are also a number of more complete examples here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/tree/master/examples